# Schema.org markup for listing of provided services

Tags: seo, schema.org

I am trying to improve SEO for a local plumber website. I am using the following elements in the contact section:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Plumber">  
 <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
 <span itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
```

I also want to list the services that are provided. These are shown in a list and include: Boiler services, Installation, Fix leaking taps etc.

How would I markup these multiple services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an [OfferCatalog](https://schema.org/OfferCatalog) of [Offer](https://schema.org/Offer)s which are the provided [Service](https://schema.org/Service)s:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Plumber">
    <span itemprop="name">Mr. Plumber</span>
    <!-- other properties e.g. address -->
    <ul itemprop="hasOfferCatalog" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
            <span itemprop="name">Services offered</span>
            <ul itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferCatalog">
                <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                    <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
                        <span itemprop="name">Service one name</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                    <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
                        <span itemprop="name">Service two name</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Google Structured Data Testing Tool]

This is based on the example for an [OfferCatalog](https://schema.org/OfferCatalog).